# Golang: Can you wrap a Package in an Interface?

Tags: go, duck-typing

I'm writing a simple library to assist with common assertions.

```
type Test interface {
    Fatalf(string, ...interface{})
}

func IsTrue(statement bool, message string, test Test) {
    if !statement {
       test.Fatalf(message)
    }
}
```

I noticed that the `log` package actually has a compatible implementation of `Fatalf(string, ...interface{})` and it'd be great if the `IsTrue` method could be invoked accordingly:

```
IsTrue(false, "false wasn't true", log)
```

But I get the error `use of package log not in selector`. Is there any way to use or wrap a package to make this pattern work or is this not possible?

Comment: Here's a nugget of wisdom about what you're doing in the go FAQ: http://golang.org/doc/faq#testing_framework .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can hope for is to wrap it in a blank struct like so:

```
type internalLog struct{}

func (il internalLog) Fatalf(s string, i ...interface{}) {
    log.Fatalf(s, i...)
}
```

In general, since packages are not types in Go, they cannot satisfy anything. You have to wrap them in another type in order to simulate them satisfying an interface.

Edit:

As Caleb mentions (and I forgot about), the package `log` **in specific** has the function `New` which returns a *log.Logger which will satisfy the `Test` interface in your case (as well as most other package-level `log` functions). However, *in general* if no such type is provided you must wrap the package like I showed above.

Comment: any changes/improvements/sugar in the later versions since 2013?

Answer (score 2):

I would make a default provider using `log` that can be overwritten:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

type TestLogger interface{
    Fatalf(string, ...interface{})
}

var DefaultLogger TestLogger

func init() {
    DefaultLogger = log.New(os.Stderr, "", log.LstdFlags)
}

func IsTrue(statement bool, message string) {
    if !statement {
       DefaultLogger.Fatalf(message)
    }
}

func main() {
    IsTrue(false, "MESSAGE")
}
```

If someone was using your package they could do something like this:

```
type MyCustomImplementation struct {}

func (this MyCustomImplementation) Fatalf(msg string, args ... interface{}) {
    // do whatever in here
}

some_package.DefaultLogger = MyCustomImplementation{}
```